Запуск и остановка задач в планировщике по клику
Есть 2 задачи в планировщике задач windows. Подскажите пожалуйста способ по клику останавливать и запускать эти задачи (не выполнить а - включить\отключить сами задачи). Bat, vbs или еще что-то. Буду благодарен (сами задачи запускают другие файлы через определенный промежуток времени, настройка в самом планировщике не требуется).

Ну наверное искать в гугле "kill process in windows cmd" и сделать из команды cmd файл.

этих процессов нет в диспетчере задач, они в планировщике задач

@sffdss так не бывает

Тогда sc \\localhost stop wuauserv

А, стоп. В сервисах или в шедулере?

добавил скрин, выделил красным задачи в планировщике задач которые хотелось бы активировать и выключать по клику чтобы каждый раз не лазить в планировщик и в ручную отключать их и включать

автоматизация управления задачами решается как через PS-модуль ScheduledTasks, так и консольную утилиту ОС Schtasks.exe
